# Not sending scheduled reports by email with JasperReports Server

Tags: java, smtp, quartz-scheduler, jasperserver

I'm dealing with an issue with *JasperReports Server*, i have it running in CentOS, i'm trying to schedule and send reports by email but still no success.
I just configured the js.quartz.properties file as follows:

```
report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=myemailaddress@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=Mypassword
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=myemailaddress@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtps
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=465
report.scheduler.web.deployment.uri=http://etcetcetc.com:8080/jasperserver
```

also my applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml file:

```
<bean id="reportSchedulerMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.host}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.password}"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.port}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
   </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

I tried with ports 25, 465 and 587, disabling firewall, using smtp protocol instead of smtps and still i'm not able to accomplish this task, below you can see the error i'm gettins, i'll appreciate your help here.

```
No se completó la notificación de error de trabajo. Se produjo un error al enviarlo.
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.java:123)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJob.java:942)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:538)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:219)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378133/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-465-response-1

Comment: @MiguelMartinez You can also check this post: [JasperReport Server email by Sendgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37371020/876298). There are a lot of question on SO about JRS and sending email

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers, i've been trying with the most of the solutions described on SO but still no success on this, even i just went and copy the same configuration from one post who said it worked but still failing, any other ideas about this friends?